# how to pull selected radio button value?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have multiple radio buttons in my HTML and while I am clicking on SAVE button then i want to check with radio button is selected.

HTML Code

```
<div id="" class="workdlowreasons" *ngFor="let reason of workflowReasons; let i=index;">
        <input type="radio" name="reason"  id="reason_{{i}}" value="{{reason.reason}}"
        [checked]="i === 0">
        <label for="reason_{{i}}">{{reason.reason}}</label>
        </div>
```

DOM HTML

```html
<form _ngcontent-c7="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}--><div _ngcontent-c7="" class="workdlowreasons" id="">
            <input _ngcontent-c7="" name="reason" type="radio" id="reason_0" value="Not Relevany to Patient">
            <label _ngcontent-c7="" for="reason_0">Not Relevany to Patient</label>
            </div><div _ngcontent-c7="" class="workdlowreasons" id="">
            <input _ngcontent-c7="" name="reason" type="radio" id="reason_1" value="Patient Shifted">
            <label _ngcontent-c7="" for="reason_1">Patient Shifted</label>
            </div><div _ngcontent-c7="" class="workdlowreasons" id="">
            <input _ngcontent-c7="" name="reason" type="radio" id="reason_2" value="Patient Discharged">
            <label _ngcontent-c7="" for="reason_2">Patient Discharged</label>
            </div><div _ngcontent-c7="" class="workdlowreasons" id="">
            <input _ngcontent-c7="" name="reason" type="radio" id="reason_3" value="Another Nurse Attending">
            <label _ngcontent-c7="" for="reason_3">Another Nurse Attending</label>
            
            <input _ngcontent-c7="" class="btn-primary btn" id="submitdecline" name="submitdecline" type="button" value="Save">
        </form>
```

Comment: what you want you need get the selected radio button value ?

Comment: I have a question and its 2 option (Yes/No). I select 1 option and submit it. then another question comes from server and i added new question in same array so I can view both question. till here everything is working fine. Now when I add new question in same array then in DOM html Re-rendered and it deselect my previous seletion(which i selected for Question 1). I want DOM HTML should not refresh and it just add new question which comes in array. OR selection should not deselect. Hope i am able to clear my issue.